# Genexus GAM Multiple Applications With one GAM DB SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, genexus-gam

Is there a way to use Single Sign On in GAM for multiple applications using the same GAM Database?

Answer (score 2):

No, the way to achieve SSO is using the feature as [documented](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?25385).
Note that separating the GAM clients from the GAM Identity Provider allows you to easier update your systems: GAM Identity provider may evolve to GAM 4.0 database schema while clients may still keep with GAM 3.0.6 database schema. 
(connection to provider is via services, and services layer remains backward compatible)

Note: GAM 4.0 database schema is shipped with GeneXus Salto